# How to insert arrays into objects that are inside an array? For ng2-charts / Charts.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chart.js, ng2-charts

Let's say I have 2 arrays:

```
var array1 = [1,1,1];
var array2 = [2,2,2];
```

How do I create the parent array with the 2 objects shown below?

(I'm trying to insert the given arrays above into a parent array with 2 objects, but I also still need to create the objects so that they include the keys shown.  This is to comply with the ng2-charts ChartDataSets type.)

```
// below is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I only have the 2 arrays above so far
[
  { data : array1, label: 'some label1' },
  { data : array2, label: 'some label2' },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = [1, 1, 1];
let arr2 = [2, 2, 2];
let reqArray = [arr1, arr2].map((ele, ind) => {
  return {
    data: ele,
    label: `some label${ind+1}`
  }
});
console.log(reqArray)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's works great!  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using the list of below statements you can achieve the above array of objects.

```
var array1 = [1,1,1];
var array2 = [2,2,2];
var arrObj = [];
var tempObj = {};
tempObj.data = array1;
tempObj.lable = "test1";
arrObj.push(tempObj);
tempObj.data = array2;
tempObj.lable = "test1";
arrObj.push(tempObj);
```

"arrObj" has the sample output that you wanted

Comment: please check your output will get some what like repeated array

Answer (score 0):

use map and spread operator

```
const array1 = [1,1,1];
const array2 = [2,2,2];

const parentArr = [
  { label: 'some label1' },
  { label: 'some label2' },
]

function a (array) {
  return parentArr1 = parentArr.map(it => {
    return {...it, data: array }
  })
}

console.log(a(array1))
console.log(a(array2))
```

Comment: `array` is undefined, you see you aren't passing anything when calling `a()`. I am testing again, please test also